# Slider revolution wordpress plug in

Tags: wordpress, revolution-slider

Hi I am using slider revolution. The editor is not showing the whole slide content. I'm new to wordpress and the slides we're already created. I just need to do some changes. I can't seem to figure this out.

[image]

Comment: press ctrl+mouse wheel up down  and it will show full text then select and edit it

Comment: If i do ctrl+mouse scroll, i am only zooming in and out the browser. The editor width is adjusting but the height keeps the same. @RajKumarBhardwaj

Answer (score 1):

If I am right you want to edit the text which is not currently showing full into your r-slider. 
so go to your editor and make zoom less it will show you all text make changes and save it and set the zoom previous positions with ctrl+0

Before edit image 
[image]

and how can I edit image

[image]

Thanks

Comment: I did zooming the browser. the editor keeps the same height. i have contents on the top and bottom that are not showing